# Silverlight Textbox: Text wrapping without a fixed width

Tags: silverlight

My Textblock isn't wrapping unless I give it a fixed width. The problem is that I don't know what the width should be, as it needs to simply take up whatever's left.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Value">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>



<localControls:DetailRegion>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="230">
        <TextBlock Text="Beliefs and Goals:" Style="{StaticResource Label}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BeliefsAndGoals}" Style="{StaticResource Value}" />
    </StackPanel>
</localControls:DetailRegion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. As always, the problem is the StackPanel. If I switch to a grid with two columns (one auto, the other *) then it works as expected.

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Beliefs &amp; Goals:" Style="{StaticResource Label}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BeliefsAndGoals}" Style="{StaticResource Value}" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```